# PageloadTimeout() not working in IE11 with selenium 3.4

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

IE11 throws the error below when I use pageLoad to make selenium wait until the page get loads, where otherwise it works fine in chrome and Firefox irrespective if i use in my @test or in my actual method. I am using java with selenium 3.4

### Error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Invalid timeout type specified: page load
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JavascriptExecutor` for pageload as below:

```
private static boolean isloadComplete(WebDriver driver)
{
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("loaded")
            || ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Implicit wait instead of this, It works in IE, Chrome and Firefox

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Reason:  When the page loading time exceeded the time We are given then it throws `TimeoutException`.

While  Implicit wait set this once it have the scope until the WebDriver instance destroy.

Comment: I am using implicitly wait as an alternative to this, But why is this failing in IE alone ?? Is that IE doesn't support this particular wait??

Comment: May be it is driver issue I guess, some time I also got this issue, Please upvote if answer helps u

Comment: Reason:  When the page loading time exceeded the time We are given then it throws `TimeoutException`.

While  Implicit wait set this once it have the scope until the WebDriver instance destroy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explaining me . Since implicit wait is more of a common wait which wait for all the elements to load in general , i want something which is specific to the page load.